# Python webscraping handshake failed, if statement in order to handle the error?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping a website using selenium to pull data based off user input, if the user inputs an invalid input this is what is returned by the scraper. Is there a way I can write an if/else statement to catch this error and retry the input?

[image]

Code snippet (example code but not the exact code as it is much larger and more complicated, this pulls same error, though):

```
import re
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

trn = "https://tracker.gg/valorant/profile/riot/"

playertag = input("Enter the player's name followed by the tag: (example: Eazy#Pzy)\n")

player, tag = playertag.split('#')

#Opens browser

driver = Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')

# Moves window from view

driver.set_window_position(-10000, 0)

# URL creation using input variables and Tracker URL

driver.get(f'{trn}{player}%23{tag}\n')

rank = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "valorant-rank-bg")

for i in rank:
    rank = i.get_attribute('innerText')

print(rank)
```

Comment: Only as an improvement, paste the code and don't make a screenshot so it will be easier found by search engines.
Add more clarification:  What user input and how is it used? What functions are you calling?

Comment: @Daraan I've added a snippet. The user input is used to fill a URL which then scrapes data from a page. If the URL returns a 404 the above screenshot is what occurs.

Comment: You need to add a minimal reproducible example: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, then update your question.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus updated it, this should pull the same error I am getting (using the input "Eazy#hfiuh" in posh.

Comment: Page you confirmed is a `404 PAGE NOT FOUND` page. Please confirm a valid page/profile.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus sorry if I was not clear, the objective is to retry the input when the 404 page not found occurs. But a valid profile example if you need it is [here](https://tracker.gg/valorant/profile/riot/Eazy%23Pzy/overview).